# issue with fading in and out in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, fadein, fadeout

I am developing an online test application and I am extracting all the questions from the xml file to a jsp page...All the questions are displayed using a for loop in jsp... Now i don`t want all the questions in a single page , rather i want them one by one to be displayed as the user clicks the "next" button . So here is the code what i am using and it is displaying only the first and the 2nd question and from the 3rd question on ,, its fading in and again fading out ...without clicking the "next " button...need some suggestions here...thanks... HERE IS THE CODE:

and the jsp code..:

METHOD="post">

```
<%

    for(int i = 0; i < javapaperList.size(); i++){
        JavaPaper paper = javapaperList.get(i);
        String text = paper.getText();
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(text, "##");
        int tokensint = tokens.countTokens();

%>

<div class="questions" id=<%out.println("qx" + paper.getId());%> style="display:none" > 

<%
            while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            %>  
                <label class="questiontext" ><%=tokens.nextToken()%></label><br>
         <%             
            }
         %>

         <BR>
         <BR>
         <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="A" id=<% out.println("A" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
         <% out.println(paper.getOptiona());%>
        <BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="B" id=<% out.println("B" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
        <% out.println(paper.getOptionb());%>
        <BR> 
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="C" id=<% out.println("C" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
        <% out.println(paper.getOptionc());%>
        <BR>
         <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="D" id=<% out.println("D" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
         <% out.println(paper.getOptiond());%>
        <BR> 
         <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME=<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%> VALUE="E" id=<% out.println("E" + paper.getId()); %> onClick="rboc(this)" class="option">
         <% out.println(paper.getOptione());%>
         <br>
         <br>
        <textarea name="<%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%>" id=<% out.println("q" + paper.getId()); %>  style="display:none" onClick="clearContents(this)"><%out.println("question" + paper.getId());%></textarea>
        <br>

        <%
        if(b!=false||x==10){
            x++;
            %>
             <BR> </div>
                <input type="button" id="next" value="NEXT"  ></input>
                <BR>         
            <%
        }
      }
        %>
        <input type='hidden' value=<%out.println(javapaperList.size());%> id="javapaperlist"/>



        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </FORM>
```

Comment: the jQuery code is here..: "I am stuck with the concept of fading in and out in jQuery"(search this string in search box);

Comment: Please post the generated code (from the browser's View/Source), not the JSP.  You will then be able to get help from everyone who knows HTML/JS, not just those who also know JSP and can figure out what your JSP is doing.